# Static JS file not compiled for a Ruby on Rails project on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having difficulties deploying my Ruby on Rails project to Heroku around static javascript files, my /app/assets/javascripts/application.js file looks like this

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/effect-blind
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require main
//= require_tree .
```

Initially the jquery files and my own custom JS file (called main.js under /app/assets/javascripts/) were not being loaded, I since included the rails_12factor gem in my Gemfile like so

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Now the jquery files have been compiled but the main.js file is still being ignored. What must I do so that the file is also included in the compilation process?

Answer (score 0):

in `config/initializers/assets.rb` add or modify existing

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.js )
```

Comment: I've added that, but the file is still being ignored

Comment: are you sure? it should not be linked to your pages as a separate file, but it's contents should be added to application.js in production. You could also try not to load it in application.js, but add another javascript_include_tag to application.html.erb

Comment: Yes, I am sure, because the functions I have defined in that file are not found. I have even trying to include it in a separate javascript_include_tag that lead to a link to /javascripts/main.js (for some reason) even though the file was precompiled to a different location (assets/javascripts/main-#hash#.js)